Save the project in jupyter notebook
I recently installed Anaconda and Jupiter notebook, but when I write my code in Jupiter, I can't download from the download as section with different formats like .py or .ipynb.That means it doesn't give me the download options.Can you guide me?I will be grateful.
I tried installing nbconvert but still the download options are not enabled.

It sounds like you may be looking for 'Save Notebook as...' or for 'Save and Export Notebook as...'? Also what version of the Jupyter software are you using? Flavor and version information would be best. If you have installed Anaconda and Jupyter is working then you already have nbconvert there. (Note the way I say about the installation. Anaconda comes with Jupyter so there's be no reason to install Jupyter itself. But maybe you were just emphasizing that Jupyter was there and didn't mean you install it separate?) There'd be no reason to add nbconvert again ...

 and in fact may start causing your problems.
